# Youtube Videos look pixelated on Macbook M1

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, video

I recently noticed that YouTube videos look pixelated on MacBook M1 on Chrome, FireFox, & Brave.

I have disabled **Hardware-Acceleration** on these browsers but still have the same issue.

Safari & Edge Chromium renders the video perfectly and there is no pixelation on any of the videos I tested.

Resolution: 1080p
Tested Video: Dolby Atmos trailer
Video Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd_6WN9GVtQ

On Chrome / FireFox / Brave

[image]

On Safari

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found out an issue regarding the Blurry visuals in YouTube. Chrome/FireFox/Brave uses AV1 video codec to render videos whereas Safari uses VP09 which renders it perfectly. I had to change the Video playback settings in youtube to render it in VP09 as Safari does it by default.

You can also use a helper chrome plugin to mitigate this issue:

Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enhanced-h264ify/omkfmpieigblcllmkgbflkikinpkodlk?hl=en

FireFox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/enhanced-h264ify/